# ConnectTimeout not always blocking reading from inputstream?

Tags: java, timeout, urlconnection

In my application, I open UrlConnections, and I set connection timeout.
Sometimes, the timeout is thrown, but the inputstream is still readable (and do contain data)

I successfully reproed this using the following code:

```
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    long length = 0;

    while (length == 0) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.worldofwargraphs.com").openConnection());
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1); // 1ms
            connection.connect();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            try {
                byte[] buf = new byte[8196];
                try (InputStream is0 = connection.getInputStream(); InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(is0, 8196)) {
                    if (is0 != null) {
                        int ret = 0;
                        while ((ret = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            length += ret;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex2);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(length);
```

As you can see in this code, I try to open a connection with a small timeout (1ms) to make sure that the connection timeouts. Then I try to read the inputstream

The thing is that, sometimes when trying to read the stream I get a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` (which is what I would expect), but the loop *sometimes* ends, displaying the number of bytes read (32912)

Could anyone explain me why this second behavior sometimes happens ?
I tried to google it, but found nothing about this.

Thanks

Comment: You log `ex` after you caught `ex2`?

Comment: No need in this example, since I use `ex2` for displaying that I correctly got an exception when trying to read the stream. `ex` is only here to go in the "catch" part of the code

Comment: I mean, if `ex2` is thrown, you mistakenly do `log(ex)` instead of `log(ex2)`. that's why you see "connect timeout" in the log.

Comment: Indeed. But it won't fix the problem. This log() part was only to display a message on System.err ... So we just see that we have an error which is good :)

Comment: I fixed it and retried - same stuff

Answer (score 0):

Your ridiculously short connect timeout expired, but the connection subsequently completed, so you were able to read. Note that setting a connection timeout doesn't set a read timeout, so the read blocked until data was available.

EDIT: In any case your code is wrong. You should set a realistic connect timeout and close the socket if you get it. Continuing to the read code after a connect exception doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I put this timeout to make sure I repro the problem I observe in my real program.
But is the exception sometimes thrown, and sometimes not (ex2)

Comment: Either, depending on whether the connection really completed or not. Your code is wrong in any case, see edit.